DataDog not tracing @Service annotated class that uses Kotlin's operator fun invoke
I have the following service class in a Spring Boot (2.7.12) application
@Service
class GetAllUsers(val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    operator fun invoke(): List<User> {
        return userRepository.findAll()
    } 
}

And I'm tracing it using the DD_TRACE_METHODS env var
DD_TRACE_METHOD: "com.application.user.GetAllUsers[invoke]"

However, when I make an API call, only the Controller and Repository methods are shown in the trace (UsersController.getAll --> UserRepository.findAll).
Even strange. If I add a method inside the invoke method and add it to the list of methods to trace, DataDog shows the class and the invoke methods in the trace. Example:
@Service
class GetAllUsers(val userRepository: UserRepository) {

    operator fun invoke(): List<User> {
        hello()
        return userRepository.findAll()
    }

    fun hello(){
      //Does nothing
    }
}

DD_TRACE_METHOD: "com.application.user.GetAllUsers[invoke, hello]"

Trace:
UsersController.getAll --> GetAllUsers.invoke --> UserRepository.findAll

How to show the traces for invoke methods correctly without creating this method?

if you call the service invoke method datadog probably show it. this looks strange by design, a @Service class named as "GetAllUsers" I think this should have been UserService and in there you should have GetAllUsers function. I dont write kotlin everyday but I know spring, just wanted to share my 2 cents. if you put a reproducer I can dig more.
